# Why is mprotect a distinct syscall from mmap

Tags: linux, memory-management, system-calls, mmap, mprotect

I was working with syscalls relating to virtual memory lately. From the manual of `mmap` I know that it can be very powerful when `MAP_FIXED` flag is set, creating new mappings everywhere in the memory.

> MAP_FIXED
> Don't interpret addr as a hint: place the mapping at exactly
> that address.  addr must be suitably aligned: for most
> architectures a multiple of the page size is sufficient;
> however, some architectures may impose additional
> restrictions.  **If the memory region specified by addr and len
> overlaps pages of any existing mapping(s), then the overlapped
> part of the existing mapping(s) will be discarded**.  If the
> specified address cannot be used, mmap() will fail.
> Software that aspires to be portable should use the MAP_FIXED
> flag with care, keeping in mind that the exact layout of a
> process's memory mappings is allowed to change significantly
> between kernel versions, C library versions, and operating
> system releases.  Carefully read the discussion of this flag
> in NOTES!

My question is, why there is a distinct syscall `mprotect` from `mmap`, given that `mmap` can do the exact same job by creating a new mapping with the same `fd` and `offset`, and set the new `prot` you want?

In my opinion, all operations about VM can be done ultimately with `mmap` and `munmap`, for those operations are basically just playing with the page table. Can someone tell me if this is a bad idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `mprotect` if you want to change the permissions on an existing region of memory, while keeping its contents intact.

`mmap` can't do this.  If you use `mmap` with `MAP_FIXED` to create a new mapping at the same address, then the region's previous contents will be replaced by the contents of the new file you mapped, or zeros if using `MAP_ANONYMOUS`.

Using the same `fd` and `offset` does not solve this.  If the map was originally created with `MAP_ANONYMOUS` (as is the case for most dynamically allocated memory) then there is no `fd`.  Or, if the region was mapped to a file but with `MAP_PRIVATE`, then the contents could have been modified in your process's memory without being written back to the file.  Attempting to map the file again with `mmap` will lose the modified data and replace it with the file's original contents.